# Multiple TSQL sequences in one sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sequence

I need to run sequence number for all of my customers in my SQL Server database.

I have about 1000 customers, I need each and one of them have their own sequence?

How can that be done in TSQL?

Is it possible to make one sequence to serve all purposes?

It doesn't sounds reasonable to created 1000 sequences.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Does each customer need unique sequensial numbers independent of other customers, or do you need to share the same sequence between all customers?

Comment: Each customer should have its own sequence of numbers.

Comment: What are you using it for? This seems to me like it could be an XYProblem. Perhaps there is some other solution you didn't think about...

Answer (score 0):

Sequence will give you only one number series. To have one per each customer, and I would assume new customers can also appear, the only way I can think of is to create a table for the sequences. You could just have a column for the customer code and int column for the sequence.

If your database needs these sequences really often (in scale of several per second), this could easily become a bottleneck, but I assume here that's not the case.

Comment: I do have situation where I have multiple actions simultaneously, causing this locking/bottleneck situation?

Comment: It is of course possible, I would check that the locks happen only for the rows, not the whole page because the page would contain most likely quite many different customers